# Density analysis with two polygons in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, density

I'm a Norwegian student currently conducting a series of site analyzes for a city. In that context I wish to create a building density map but struggle a bit to find out how.

I have made a fishnet polygon of 50x50 meter and wish to find out how much built area there is in each of these squares. My goal is to color the squares according to how much percent of the squares are built area. Both the fishnet and the buildings are polygons and are editable. Please see the image.

Can anyone help me perform the analysis?

[image]

Comment: What licenses do you have access to? Depending on this, there are several approaches for example "Summerize Within (Analysis)".

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that worked perfectly!

Comment: You could also use the Union tool.

Comment: You could also just define the cell size of the density tool to the same as your fishnet.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways how to do it. Many are already covered on this site as well.
Depending on licenses, you can use `Summerize Within (Analysis)` in ArcGIS Pro for this purpose.